# JAXB: @XmlEnumValue missed in class file

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations

I have a enum

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnum;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnumValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "DataObjectType")
@XmlEnum
public enum DataObjectType {
    @XmlEnumValue("Number")
    NUMBER,
    @XmlEnumValue("String")
    STRING,
    @XmlEnumValue("Percent")
    PERCENT,
    @XmlEnumValue("Time")
    TIME,
    @XmlEnumValue("Duration")
    DURATION
}
```

eventhough **@XmlEnumValue** Annotation  @Retention(value=**RUNTIME**) ,It found missing in class file. 
While debugging through Java decompiler class content will be like this

```
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnum;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnumValue;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

  @XmlType(name="DataObjectType")
  @XmlEnum
  public enum DataObjectType
  {
    NUMBER, 

    STRING, 

    PERCENT, 

    TIME, 

    DURATION;
  }
```

there is no @XmlEnumValue anywhere(**expect import**).
Why this missed in class file? How can I change return value?
Please help me on this?

Comment: the compiler removes the @XmlEnumValue ; this is a normal behavior.

Comment: @OhadR Then how JAXB knows to convert custom value?